# Parsing compare_and_swap

Tags: concurrency, synchronization

I am trying to parse compare_and_swap, because honestly I don't understand a thing.

```
do { while (compare_and_swap(&lock, 0, 1) != 0)
; /* do nothing */
/* critical section */
lock = 0;
/* remainder section */
} while (true);



int compare and swap(int *value, int expected, int new_value) {
int temp = *value;
if (*value == expected)
*value = new_value;
return temp;
}
```

let's assume lock is set to 0;

1st: compare and swap returns 0, lock is set to 1, critical section is ran, lock is set to 0.

rinse and repeat

I don't know if I parsed it well, but is it possible that compare and swap takes 1 less cycle than test_and_set to do the same thing (insure concurrency of threads)?

Comment: What do you mean by "takes 1 less cycle"?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what you are actually asking here, but that is not a correct implementation of `compare_and_swap`, as it is not atomic.

A correct, atomic implementation will generally take advantage of a compare-and-swap CPU instruction. E.g. in x86 `LOCK CMPXCHG`. However, you are probably much better off using a  function provided by the system library for performing compare-and-swap (such as `InterlockedCompareExchange` in the Windows API), or the compare-exchange functions of `std::atomic<>` in C++11.

Comment: I am just asking if you can parse it or verify what i've done is correct. It doesn't matter if it's a correct implementation or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse" here?  If you want to determine if the *syntax* is valid (C/C++ I assume), why don't you actually try compiling it? If we assume that it's C-like pseudo-code, and is the general *concept* correct, then the answer is "no" for the reasons I gave above.